# c++ gRPC CompletionQueue is FILO?

Tags: asynchronous, grpc, stub

i use `grpc::CompletionQueue` in my programm, you can also find the example in 
"`grpc/examples/cpp/helloword/greeter_async_clients.cc`". 
The problem code as follow!

```
    // stub_->PrepareAsyncSayHello() creates an RPC object, returning
    // an instance to store in "call" but does not actually start the RPC
    // Because we are using the asynchronous API, we need to hold on to
    // the "call" instance in order to get updates on the ongoing RPC.
    call->response_reader =
        stub_->PrepareAsyncSayHello(&call->context, request, &cq_);

    // StartCall initiates the RPC call
    call->response_reader->StartCall();

    // Request that, upon completion of the RPC, "reply" be updated with the
    // server's response; "status" with the indication of whether the operation
    // was successful. Tag the request with the memory address of the call object.
    call->response_reader->Finish(&call->reply, &call->status, (void*)call);
```

The Client send `1,2,3...100` to Server, but the Server get the number list is "`100,99,98...2,1`". Why? i could not find any source code about this... thank you very much

and does is Nagle Algorithm for gRPC?

Answer (score 0):

`CompletionQueue` is somewhat of a misnomer.  They will return events in the order they finish (rather than the order they are issued).

gRPC C++ will disable Nagle Algorithm by default.